# Setting contentInset on UITableView after coming back from different thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios, uitableview

How can  I set the content inset on a UITableView after coming back from a separate thread?

Here is some code to get the gist of what I am doing, feel free to provide suggestions outside of the scope of this question as well.

My main goal is to collapse the area that the webview would go into (the area above the table created by the contentInset) if there is no ad available.

```
//In View did Load
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(getBannerAdContent) toTarget:self withObject:nil];


-(void)getBannerAdContent
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.18:83/PhotoGalleryService.svc/LoadBannerAd/"]];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadBannerAd:) withObject:html waitUntilDone:NO];
    [pool release];
}


-(void)loadBannerAd:(NSString*)html
{
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 2, 300, 40)];

    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    webView.delegate = self;
    webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
    webView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    [webView release];
    UITableView *myTableView = (UITableView*)[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0 ];
    //The following line is doing nothing.
    myTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44,0.0,0,0.0);
}
```

Any help you can give me would be much appreciated.

EDIT: 
A little more thorough of an explanation...

In my view did load I spark off a separate thread.  This thread loads the html from a service i set up, and then sets that on the webview.  However, as I'm stepping through, before it gets to the line

```
myTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44,0.0,0,0.0);
```

The table view is already loaded, and then the above line has no effect.

Cheers,

Comment: What's your question? Your code appears to set the `contentInset`, so I don't understand what you need help with.

Comment: the contentInset has no affect when I'm coming off of a separate thread.  hence the  //The following line is doing nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

contentInset sets the inset size, but doesn't scroll your tableview to display it.  After setting the contentInset, set the contentOffset if you want it to scroll up to show the top of the table view.

```
myTableView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
```

Comment: I don't know if it's just iOS7, but setting the contentOffset to 0 while there is a top inset will not scroll to the top of the view. To achieve the scroll-to-top effect, you have to set the offset to CGPointMake(0, -scrollView.contentInset.top)

Answer (score 0):

For Swift5 and UITableView

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if shouldAddContentInset {
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -tableView.contentInset.top)
    }
}
```

And then from some callback function or delegate:

```
func gotResponseFromSomewhere() {
    shouldAddContentInset = true
    viewDidLayoutSubviews()
}
```